# Map from T1 space to compact metric space has partial limit.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Consider map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ from T1 (connected) space to compact metric space at point a
I want to generalize results from calculus -
1)bounded sequence has partial limit (i consider sequence as map from cofinite space over $ℕ$ - T1 connected space)
2)locally bounded at $a$ real function $f$ has partial limit at $a$.

I proved that standart diffenition of partial limit ($\exists x_{n} \rightarrow a\ f(x_{n}) \rightarrow\ b$) equivalent to $\forall Ob \forall Oa\ f[Oa\setminus{a}]\cap Ob$, and proved that for considered map $f$ true that  $\forall Oa\ \exists\ p \forall Op\ ((Op\setminus{p})\cap f[Oa\setminus{a}])$. So i need to imply from this, that $\exists\ p \forall Oa\ \forall Op\ Op\cap f[Oa\setminus{a}]$. Intuitivelly, we should come to such p, "shrinking" Oa, because ($Oa \subset Ua$ and $(Op\setminus{p})\cap f[Oa\setminus{a}]$) implies $((Op\setminus{p})\cap f[Ua\setminus{a}])$ - for any a-neighbourhood there is p, such that any p-neighbourhood intersects image of a-neighbourhood and all top. How to prove strictly?

Comment: With sequences theory i see way to prove, if X connected, and Y - complete, building sequnce of Oa, there always p which  is limit point of f[Oa], so we maps Oa to p and build sequence of p, which has converging subsequence in complete compact. But sequences - what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I resolved it. If {a} - open, there is Oa minimal by inclusion, and corresponding p is answer. Otherwise, case when set of p is finite - same, some of them closure point for all f[Oa]. If it infinite - it has limit point P in compact space, any neighborhood of P contains infinite number of p, so for any Oa there is p in OP together with some Op each of them intersect f[Oa], and so, OP intersect f[Oa]